# How to execute a batch of redirect rules based on a specific condition in .htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a requirement to redirect to specific URLs if the request URL is some other specific URL. But all of them contains a specific word. For example, all the URLs will have /personal. But not all the URLs containing /personal should not be redirected. There is a list of 170 request and response URLs. But there is no common segment in the URL. Is there any way to handle this using .htaccess without affecting the performance of the website? Is there any way to execute a batch of requests, only if the URL is containing the text /personal?

Please find some examples below:

Request URL: example.com/en/personal/usage/calculator

Redirect URL: anotherdomain.com/en/guest/personal-and-business/calculator

Request URL: example.com/en/personal/content/content-1

Redirect URL: anotherdomain.com/en/guest/communication-solutions/new-content

Comment: Could you please post some URLs on form of from this URL to this URL this should be served format in your question and let us know then

Comment: Please find some examples below:

Request URL: https://www.example.com/en/personal/usage/calculator
Redirect URL: https://anotherdomain.com/en/guest/personal-and-business/calculator

Request URL: https://www.example.com/en/personal/content/content-1
Redirect URL: https://anotherdomain.com/en/guest/communication-solutions/new-content

Comment: Request you to please update them in your question in TEXT format in CODE TAGS. Eg--> `http://localhost:80/singh_balle_balle` OR `http://localhost:80/singh_test/blabla/foo/` kind of in CODE TAGS, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting samples in your question. But what is the Logic of changing URI from `en/personal/usage/calculator` TO `en/guest/personal-and-business/calculator` could you please explain it, without that we couldn't help in writing Rules IMHO.

Comment: Because, we have developed a new website. Some of the old URLs should be redirected to the new website URL. There are almost 170 URLs

Comment: I get that even I had written also basic rules but then how URL a will know I need to go to X in new domain? Without having any logic or relation here? Is my question. There should be someway no how you are recognizing program should also do the same of there is NO WAY then we need to hard code them kindly confirm once here.

Comment: Do the two domains `example.com` and `anotherdomain.com` point to different places or the same place? Ideally, they would point to different places. Does the old domain still host a website, or is the purpose of the old domain only for redirection?

Comment: Yes. Both are in different places. We have separated one type of users from the old portal to new. So, the people coming to the old portal should be redirected to the new portal's that exact content.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you are still hosting the "old" portal at `example.com` - this is still a valid website? If so, do these URLs that you want to redirect still exist as valid URLs/pages at the old site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading OP's post looks like there are 2 requests here, 1st- to change OLD domain to new domain then 2nd- to change OLD URI to NEW URI(without any specific logic).

So we need to first change domain and then hard code one by one RewriteRUle for specific old uri to serve them through new uri like as follows as per shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine ON
###Main rules here for domain change and make sure this will be always on TOP else it will create issues.
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://anotherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

##Go with individual Rules for individual URIs, by seeing following examples.
RewriteRule ^en/personal/usage/calculator/?$ en/guest/personal-and-business/calculator [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^en/personal/content/content-1/?$ en/guest/communication-solutions/new-content [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my question is, will the above script affect the performance of the website if we add 170 URLs like this?

Comment: @JitheshBorgia, not sure, I don't have experience in handling large site etc. But 1 url 1 redirection should be OK no? problem will occur when 1 type of url is handling multiple url redirections IMHO.

Comment: @JitheshBorgia, Your welcome bhai, cheers and happy learning.